# Time difference in minutes from as a datetime column as a result of values from another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as :

```
datetime               fault
2021-08-06T09:04:00    No
2021-08-06T09:05:00    No
2021-08-06T09:06:00    Yes
2021-08-06T09:07:00    Yes
2021-08-06T09:08:00    No
```

I would like to obtain the duration of time in minutes when the fault column was YES.

So the output should be 2 minutes which is (2021-08-06T09:06:00 + 2021-08-06T09:07:00)

Comment: So you want the timediff from beginning to the time where `fault` is `yes`. For the first `yes` it will be `2` and for the second one it will be `3`?

Comment: For the first Yes it would be one minute (2021-08-06T09:06:00 - 2021-08-06T09:05:00). For the second yes it would also be one minute(2021-08-06T09:07:00 - 2021-08-06T09:06:00). The total time of yes should now be 1+1 = 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your `datetime` column to datetime objects.

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Now we should find indices with `"Yes"` in `fault` column:

```
indices = df.index[df['fault'] == "Yes"].tolist()
```

Now we can iterate over `indices` to find the column with `"Yes"` and the previous one:

Note: I am not going to check errors. However when index is `0` previous row does not exist. And you'll get error. Or get the last row. I'm not sure.

Now we get each index and the previous one. Get the time diff. And calculate the value in minutes:

```
for index in indices:
    prev = df.iloc[index - 1]
    current = df.iloc[index]
    print(pd.Timedelta(current["datetime"] - prev["datetime"]).seconds/60)
```

Maybe you can get rid of `prev` and `current` and write them directly on the calculation line:

```
for index in indices:
    print(pd.Timedelta(df.iloc[index]["datetime"] - df.iloc[index - 1]["datetime"]).seconds/60)
```

Since we calculated the values we can add them using list comprehension:

```
total_diffs = sum(
    [
        pd.Timedelta(df.iloc[index]["datetime"] - df.iloc[index - 1]["datetime"]).seconds/60
        for index in indices
    ]
)
```

Finally the whole code would be:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
indices = df.index[df['fault'] == "Yes"].tolist()


total_diffs = sum(
    [
        pd.Timedelta(df.iloc[index]["datetime"] - df.iloc[index - 1]["datetime"]).seconds/60
        for index in indices
    ]
)
```